# Tcl: Inherit from tablelist

Tags: inheritance, tcl

How can I inherit my own class from `tablelist`?
This code doesn't work (fail's on command `inherit`)

```
package require tablelist

::itcl::class myTableList {
    inherit ::tablelist
}
```

And how should be constructor written?

P.S. `tablelist` version is 4.8

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can't inherit from tablelist, as it isn't an inheritable class, you *can* wrap it and add functionality round the outside. In the simplest cases — modifying or adding methods — you can do it with just delegation. Here's how (using TclOO):

```
### This metaclass makes doing the construction look like standard Tk.
oo::class create WidgetWrapper {
    # It's a metaclass, so it inherits from oo::class
    superclass oo::class

    method unknown {methodName args} {
        # See if we actually got a widget name; do the construction if so
        if {[string match .* $methodName]} {
            set widgetName $methodName

            # There's a few steps which can't be done inside the constructor but have to
            # be at the factory level.
            set obj [my new $widgetName {*}$args]
            rename $obj $widgetName

            # Tk widget factories *MUST* return the path name as the name of the widget.
            # It *MUST NOT* be colon-qualified, and it *MUST* refer to a widget.
            return $widgetName
        }

        # Don't know what's going on; pass off to standard error generation
        next $methodName {*}$args
    }
    unexport new create unknown
}

### This does the actual wrapping.
WidgetWrapper create WrappedTablelist {
    constructor {pathName args} {
        # Make the widget and *rename* it to a known name inside the object's
        # private namespace. This is magical and works.
        rename [tablelist::tablelist $pathName {*}$args] widget
    }

    # Delegate unknown method calls to the underlying widget; if they succeed,
    # bake the delegation in more permanently as a forward.
    method unknown {methodName args} {
        try {
            return [widget $methodName {*}$args]
        } on ok {} {
            oo::objdefine [self] forward $methodName widget $methodName
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can just inherit from the `WrappedTablelist` and add/define the behaviours you want. The use of `unknown` to do the delegation initialisation is a little messy, but tablelist has a vast number of methods so listing them all here would be a bit painful.

You can probably use similar schemes with itcl, but I don't know that quite so well.

Answer (score 1):

Tablelist does not use [incr Tcl] (or any other object system for Tcl) and thus can not be inherited from.